# How to sort an array with its index?

Tags: c

I want to sort an integer array in descending order,but i want their index remains same as before.For ex:

```
arr[]={5,4,9,3,1,2}

index={0,1,2,3,4,5}
```

After sorting:

```
arr[]={9,5,4,3,2,1}

index={2,0,1,3,5,4}
```

How to do this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: You can sort pairs: structs of (value, old-index). Then, extract the second components (old-indices) in the new order.

Answer (score 2):

You Should use a structure array with fields (value , index) and then sort it based on value field. index field, therefore, shall be retained as before.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *Array;

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int ix = *(const int*)a;
    int iy = *(const int*)b;
    return Array[ix]>Array[iy] ? -1 : Array[ix]<Array[iy];
}

int main(){
    int arr[]  ={5,4,9,3,1,2};
    int index[]={0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int i, size = sizeof(index)/sizeof(*index);
    int sorted[size];
    Array = arr;
    qsort(index, size, sizeof(*index), cmp);
    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
        printf("%d ", sorted[i]=arr[index[i]]);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
        printf("%d ", index[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify a standard sorting algorithm such that instead of evaluating based on arr[i] they evaluate based on arr[index[i]] and change only values in index[i]. All sorting algorithms eventually boil down to a comparison of one element against another, all you have is an extra level of indirection.

Numerical Recipes in C is a good book available online that you can get such algorithms from, or any introduction to computer science text.